# Feedback for Android OS

Tags: android

Is there a way to give feedback about Android OS. (Not about Android apps but about the operating system itself)

This may be any kind of feedback. Might me a bug report or a feature request. Microsoft uses connect.microsoft.com for such purposes. Is there a feedback site for Android?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several different feedback channels. In decreasing order of preference, they are:

**To report bugs or request features**

Use issue tracker, available at http://b.android.com. Use the templates Tools bug report or Tools feature request.

**To discuss**

Write to forum, http://groups.google.com/group/adt-dev (new!). Please use the new forum adt-dev in place of the android-contrib one.

remember that this is not a user support forum. This forum is for people working on Android and tools. It is heavily moderated and user support questions will not go through.

For user groups and other community related lists see http://source.android.com/community.

**Other Feedback**

If you have other ideas but you don't want to file a bug or write to the forum, you can send an e-mail to the following alias:
   *tools@android.com* 
Please consider using one of the other feedback mechanisms before writing to the feedback alias.

NOTE: THE ABOVE E-MAIL ALIAS IS ONLY FOR FEEDBACK ON THE DEVELOPMENT TOOLS, NOT GENERAL ANDROID FEEDBACK!